# Free/Cheap custom search engine in multiple sites

Tags: yahoo, bing, google-custom-search

I'v been using Google Custom Search for a few months, but since few months ago they deprecated the old API, and the new one is limited to 100 queries per day. I'm looking for custom search engine with the option of searching within a list of sites.
I'v checked Yahoo BOSS API(which is pretty cheap), and I didn't notice any option of multiple site search, and so is Bing.

Did I miss something?

Thanks